# TFS 2008 Branching always adds root folder

Tags: branching-and-merging

I'm trying to create a branch for QA using TFS 2008

I have my main code in the **trunk** folder.

When I perform the branch, I select a **qa** folder which I created to be mirror the **trunk** folder.

However, when I perform the branch, it puts the trunk folder ***inside*** the qa folder, which is not what I want.  I want the qa folder to be a mirror of the trunk folder.

Is this possible with TFS 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you performing the branch operation from the root of the team project, or from the Trunk folder itself?  If you are branching from the root, then any branch created will contain the Trunk folder, whereas if you branch directly from the Trunk folder your QA folder should mirror what's in the Trunk folder.

Comment: I'm branching from the trunk folder.  That's what I find very odd about it.  I right click on the trunk folder and select Branch

Comment: So, am I right in assuming that Trunk is a folder below the root project level?  Just making sure we haven't got our wires crossed here  :-)

Comment: Are you creating the QA folder prior to branching? If so, when you select the QA folder as the branch destination, it will create a copy of the Trunk folder within the QA folder.  Delete your QA folder and perform the branch operation again, specifying the same target folder as before - the new QA folder should be created as a copy of Trunk.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted  :-)